# Mysql Insert With PHP - Not allowing characters after Space.

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code which generates a list from a field in mysql table. 
When I submit the information into another database it doesnt show anything after the space - just the first word (for example, if i choose 'robe spot' from the drop down and sumbit only 'robe' is inserted into the database)

Here is my php code:

```
<?
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // localhost will be used in most cases
// set these to your mysql database username and password.
$dbUser = 'user'; 
$dbPass = 'pass';
$dbDatabase = 'stock'; // the database you put the table into.
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("stock") or die(mysql_error()); 
$query="SELECT category FROM subcategory_table";
/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed 
in alphabetical order */
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select name='category'>";
// printing the list box select command
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){//Array or records stored in $nt
echo "<option value=$nt[category]>$nt[category]</option>";
/* Option values are added by looping through the array */
}
echo "</select>";// Closing of list box 
?>
```

I'm looking for the correct code so it allows spaces when submitting back into the database

Thank You

Comment: where is your insert query?? please post that  also

Comment: It's not a help for the question, but you should stop using mysql functions - they are depricated. Instead you can use Mysqli - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or PDO - http:php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and it's a good practice to surround the fields with ``

Comment: Yoong Kim has pointed you at a solution. You could have found this problem yourself if you had performed basic automated QA by running your HTML through [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your code as:

```
echo '<option value="' . $nt[category] . '">' . $nt[category] . '</option>';
```

The problem is the option value.
It should work.

Comment: It would help if you explained the problem was that the attribute value in the generated HTML wasn't quoted. When I first read this I though you were suggesting that using variable interpolation was the problem.

Comment: You could also just put apostrophes in the double-quoted string : `value = '$nt[category]'`.

Comment: you could put "{$var}" will look much cleaner

Comment: but I wrote the problem: "The problem is the option value". But maybe it was not so clear...but it was so obvious for me, sorry.